# Set up view controllers like Find My Friends iPad app

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, containers, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to set up my view controllers like the Find My Friends iPad app. Based on what I've found so far, I believe that I need to:

- Use a container view controller
- Make the tab bar controller the root view controller of the container view controller
- Add other view controllers, such as split view controller, as child view controllers to tab bar controller
- Add some sort of callback methods to forward messages from the parent to the child view controllers (for rotation and appearance)

Can someone please confirm that I am on the right track? Also, if you can point to or add some sample code to help me get started, I will appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. All 4 tabs on the "Find my Friends" iPad app are split views. It is actually very simple to get started with an app like that. I'm not sure what direction you are planning to take as far as content, but at least for the layout. Start a new project in Xcode and then choose master-detail application. It will automatically setup a split view with the left side as a table view and the rightside as a detail view. it will also presetup some editing methods and what nots. If you will be using core data at all, i would also highly suggest starting that with the checkmark as well. Good luck with your app!